# The display flex cable of my Windows 10 tablet died. Would HDMI out to USB C work?

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, tablet, usb-c

I own the Voyo i7 plus (Windows 10) which has an HDMI out, 2 USB A and 1 USB C port. The display flex cable is broken and not replaceable/fundable all over the internet somehow.

[image]

When I connect the tablet to a TV/external monitor through the HDMI cable, all works fine.

I would like to know if I can somehow 'solve' this issue with an 'HDMI out to USB C cable' or 'USB C to HDMI in' cable. This would serve as an 'external display flex cable' given that the internal one is not there because not buyable.

1. Would that work?
2. What are my current options except using it with an external monitor or TV?

Comment: you could measuring flex cable and by-pass all broken lines with thin jumper wire (from connector to connector, no soldering only squeeze along with flex)

Comment: or soldering repair ;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZvmFcg38As

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't have the original cable anymore, we threw it away since it was damaged. There is no place on Earth where I can buy it unfortunately (amazon, ebay, aliexpress). I was thinking about the HDMI out port and the usb C port which are located on the side of the tablet. But what kind of cable/device would I need to make it work? Thanks

Comment: you can buy another Voyo i7 plus and copy pinout for flex cable